# Infinite pooling while trying to write on psql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

Hi i'm trying to write some data from form to my postgres db,but when i hit submit the browser network status still pending..really i don't know why.
I'm using pg lib in node to do that.postgres server is on.

Here's the code:

```
app.post('/saving', function(req, res){
var age = req.param('Age');
var gender = req.param('gender');

var client = new pg.Client ({user:'app',                   database:'testhost:'localhost',    port:'5432', password:'0000'});
  client.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else {
      let sql = 'INSERT INTO public.attack (age, gender) VALUES ($1, $2)';
      let params = [ age, gender ];
      client.query(sql, params, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        client.end(function (err) {
          if (err)  throw err;
        })
      })
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: You're not sending back a response.

Answer (score 0):

### Syntax errors

You have a syntax error in your code. It's even apparent by looking at the syntax highlighting in your question:

```
var client = new pg.Client ({user:'app', database:'testhost:'localhost',
                             port:'5432', password:'0000'});
```

You have 9 single quote characters in that line so after the unmatched quote everything what should be quoted is unquoted and vice versa.

### Throwing exceptions

If you have it sorted out, try to avoid throwing exceptions all over the place and instead send a 500 error or something to the client instead of killing your server.

### Sending response

And finally, as robertklep pointed out in the comment, try sending some response. You should give at least some minimal response to the client, like:

```
res.json({ok:true});
```

or something like that because otherwise the client will wait forever.

### Reusing connections

Another thing that will not stop your code from working but is wasting resources and may cause performance problems later: You're creating a new connection to your database for every request. Making the connection once and reusing it in your request handlers will make your code perform better and it will also make it simpler, because it will take all of the `client.connect` and `client.end` nested calls outside of your request handler.